# Run a function every 100 iterations but also catch the last ones

Tags: c#

How can the following code be modified to run my insert statements 100 at a time but also run if we don't have 100 in total. Also it needs to be able to run the last few the over run the 100%. Having a very slow brain day today.

```
if (oleDataBaseConnection.HasRows())
{
    int counter = 0;

    Spinner spinner = new Spinner();

    StringBuilder postgresQuery = new StringBuilder();

    Dictionary<string, string> postgreSQLQueries = TypeConversion.GetQueryDictionary("POSTGRESQL");

    while (oleDataBaseConnection.NextRecord())
    {
        string postgreSQLInsertQuery;

        postgreSQLQueries.TryGetValue("INSERT", out postgreSQLInsertQuery);

        postgreSQLInsertQuery = postgreSQLInsertQuery.Replace("{0}", tableName);
                                    spinner.Turn();

        postgresQuery.Append(postgreSQLInsertQuery);

        postgresQuery.Append("(");

        int columnCounter = 0;

        //add a column parameter to query for each of our columns
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> t in destinationColumnData)
        {
             postgresQuery.Append(t.Key + ",");
             columnCounter++;
        }

        postgresQuery = postgresQuery.Remove(postgresQuery.Length - 1, 1);
        postgresQuery.Append(") ");

        postgresQuery.Append("VALUES (");

        //Loop through values for column names/types
        for (int i = 0; i < columnCounter; i++)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(oleDataBaseConnection.GetFieldById(i)))
            {
                 postgresQuery.Append("NULL, ");
            }
            else
            {
                 switch (foobar[i].ToUpper())
                 {
                     case "TEXT":
                         postgresQuery.Append("$$" + oleDataBaseConnection.GetFieldById(i) + "$$, ");
                         break;
                     case "GEOMETRY":
                         postgresQuery.Append("ST_GeomFromText('" + oleDataBaseConnection.GetFieldById(i) + "'), ");
                         break;
                     default:
                         postgresQuery.Append(oleDataBaseConnection.GetFieldById(i) + ", ");
                         break;
                 }
             }
         }

         postgresQuery = postgresQuery.Remove(postgresQuery.Length - 2, 2);
         postgresQuery.Append(") ");

         counter++;

         //run 100 insert statements at a time
         if (counter % 100 == 0)
         {
             postgresSQLDBConnection.PostgreSQLExecutePureSqlNonQuery(postgresQuery.ToString());

             postgresQuery.Clear();
         } 
     }
 }
```

Comment: If you know number of records beforehand you can simply decrement and test. First batch will contain fewer records, the rest will be in hundreds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that all records have been inserted after the while loop is finished if the rest value of counter divided by 100 is 0. We therefore can also draw the conclusion that there are records that still need to be inserted if the rest value of the counter divided by 100 is not 0;

So add this part directly below the while loop:

```
if (counter % 100 != 0) 
{ 
    postgresSQLDBConnection.PostgreSQLExecutePureSqlNonQuery(postgresQuery.ToString()); 

    postgresQuery.Clear(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew it wasn't far off but I'm really tired today and the grey matter hasn't woken up yet =) Time for a coffee

Answer (score 1):

Outside of the loop body, have a final cleanup run:

```
    //run 100 insert statements at a time
    if (counter % 100 == 0)
    {
        postgresSQLDBConnection.PostgreSQLExecutePureSqlNonQuery(postgresQuery.ToString());

        postgresQuery.Clear();
    } 
}
if (counter % 100 != 0)
{
    postgresSQLDBConnection.PostgreSQLExecutePureSqlNonQuery(postgresQuery.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked the main logic, but if it's already mostly working (and just not doing the last few records), then you just need to add one more insert statement outside the loop (after the loop has finished), to insert the last few records:

EDIT: Just to add, you don't need to do a `counter % 100 != 0` check, because the query will already have been cleared if `counter % 100 == 0`.

```
if (oleDataBaseConnection.HasRows())
{
    int counter = 0;

    Spinner spinner = new Spinner();

    StringBuilder postgresQuery = new StringBuilder();

    Dictionary<string, string> postgreSQLQueries = TypeConversion.GetQueryDictionary("POSTGRESQL");

    while (oleDataBaseConnection.NextRecord())
    {
        string postgreSQLInsertQuery;

        postgreSQLQueries.TryGetValue("INSERT", out postgreSQLInsertQuery);

        postgreSQLInsertQuery = postgreSQLInsertQuery.Replace("{0}", tableName);
                                    spinner.Turn();

        postgresQuery.Append(postgreSQLInsertQuery);

        postgresQuery.Append("(");

        int columnCounter = 0;

        //add a column parameter to query for each of our columns
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> t in destinationColumnData)
        {
             postgresQuery.Append(t.Key + ",");
             columnCounter++;
        }

        postgresQuery = postgresQuery.Remove(postgresQuery.Length - 1, 1);
        postgresQuery.Append(") ");

        postgresQuery.Append("VALUES (");

        //Loop through values for column names/types
        for (int i = 0; i < columnCounter; i++)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(oleDataBaseConnection.GetFieldById(i)))
            {
                 postgresQuery.Append("NULL, ");
            }
            else
            {
                 switch (foobar[i].ToUpper())
                 {
                     case "TEXT":
                         postgresQuery.Append("$$" + oleDataBaseConnection.GetFieldById(i) + "$$, ");
                         break;
                     case "GEOMETRY":
                         postgresQuery.Append("ST_GeomFromText('" + oleDataBaseConnection.GetFieldById(i) + "'), ");
                         break;
                     default:
                         postgresQuery.Append(oleDataBaseConnection.GetFieldById(i) + ", ");
                         break;
                 }
             }
         }

         postgresQuery = postgresQuery.Remove(postgresQuery.Length - 2, 2);
         postgresQuery.Append(") ");

         counter++;

         //run 100 insert statements at a time
         if (counter % 100 == 0)
         {
             postgresSQLDBConnection.PostgreSQLExecutePureSqlNonQuery(postgresQuery.ToString());

             postgresQuery.Clear();
         } 
     }
     // this is outside the main loop (but inside the HasRows check)
     // Could check if stringbuilder has just been cleared.
     if (postgresQuery.Length > 0)
     {
        postgresSQLDBConnection.PostgreSQLExecutePureSqlNonQuery(postgresQuery.ToString());
        postgresQuery.Clear();
     }
 }
```

Comment: The `counter % 100 != 0` may avoid an unnecessary round-trip to the database though (depends on whether the data access technology ignores empty queries, or still sends them to the DB)

Comment: Indeed. This line also avoids an unnecessary trip to the database: `if (postgresQuery.Length > 0)`